# Expanding space outside our galaxy

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Some other Galaxy would have its own Hubble sphere. It is possible then that we could be on the edge of someone else’s Hubble sphere. Why is it then we are not experiencing this accelerated expansion of space outside our Galaxy or Galaxy cluster?

Comment: And how do you know we are not?